# Does "make a good living" just mean "earn well"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

I would like to know if I have used "make a good living" naturally in the dialog below? Does it just mean "earn well"? Thank you.

> A: How did you afford to buy this car?
>
> B: Well, let's just say that I've been lucky enough to **make a good
> living** from some ideas I've had.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means "earn well", and it tends to apply to a longer period of time than just one's current salary, so it's most often used with present perfect or simple past, as in this example.

Answer (score 0):

B's answer suggests that they have made a good sum of money from some kind of one-off or short-term deal. To *make a good living* is to earn a regular income that enables you to live comfortably, so we would normally say "I am lucky enough to make a good living from my work."